# Cannot use an If-statement with multiple conditions (AND/OR) when looping through variant array?

Tags: excel, vba, loops, if-statement, variant-array

**Background:**

In working with some variant arrays to sort data to multiple locations based on criteria, I noticed that using an if-statement with multiple criteria flagged as false every time.  This was being used to create a dictionary, though it never made it to the dictionary aspect, due to the false response when looping only through the variant array.

I moved these to two separate if-statements and everything worked as expected.

---

**Question:**

Why am I unable to use a multi-condition if-statement when looping through data in a variant array?

---

**Code in question:**

General code to generate the variant array:

```
Public ex_arr As Variant, ex_lr As Long, ex_lc As Long
Public dc As Scripting.Dictionary 

Private Sub capture_export_array()
    With Sheets("export")
        ex_lc = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        ex_lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, ex_lc).End(xlUp).Row
        ex_arr = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(ex_lr, ex_lc)).Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Code that resulted in `False` conditions (immediate window print = 0):

```
Private Sub find_unique_items()
    Set dc = New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(ex_arr) To UBound(ex_arr)
        If InStr(ex_arr(i, ex_lc), "CriteriaA") And InStr(ex_arr(i, 4), "CriteriaB") Then dc(ex_arr(i, 2)) = ex_arr(i, 3)
    Next i
    Debug.Print dc.Count
End Sub
```

Code that resulted in desired output (immediate window print > 0):

```
Private Sub find_unique_items()
    Set dc = New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(ex_arr) To UBound(ex_arr)
        If InStr(ex_arr(i, ex_lc), "CriteriaA") Then
            If InStr(ex_arr(i, 4), "CriteriaB") Then dc(ex_arr(i, 2)) = ex_arr(i, 3)
        End If
    Next i
    Debug.Print dc.Count
End Sub
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`InStr` returns an index. As a *logical operator*, `And` wants to have `Boolean` operands. Given `Integer` operands, the `And` operator is a *bitwise operator* - truth be told, these operators are *always* bitwise; we just dub them "logical" operators when the operands are `Boolean`.

> ```
> If InStr(ex_arr(i, ex_lc), "CriteriaA") Then
> ```

This condition is implicitly coercing the returned index into a `Boolean` expression, leveraging the fact that any non-zero value will convert to `True`.

Problems start when you bring logical/bitwise operators into the equation.

> ```
> If InStr(ex_arr(i, ex_lc), "CriteriaA") And InStr(ex_arr(i, 4), "CriteriaB") Then dc(ex_arr(i, 2)) = ex_arr(i, 3)
> ```

Say the first `InStr` returns `2`, and the second returns `1`. The `If` expression becomes `If 2 And 1 Then`, so `0`. That's zero, so the condition is false.

***Wait, what?***

Think of the binary representation of 2 vs that of 1:

```
  2:  0010
  1:  0001
AND:  0000
```

Bitwise-AND yields `0`, since none of the bits line up.

---

Stop abusing implicit type conversions, and be explicit about what you really mean. What you mean to be doing, is this:

```
If (InStr(ex_arr(i, ex_lc), "CriteriaA") > 0) And (InStr(ex_arr(i, 4), "CriteriaB") > 0) Then dc(ex_arr(i, 2)) = ex_arr(i, 3)
```

(redundant parentheses for illustrative purposes only)

Now this evaluates two `Boolean` expressions, applies bitwise-AND to the two values, and correctly works as intended.

```
True: 1111
True: 1111
 AND: 1111
```

Comment: @dwirony `If 2 And 1 Then` doesn't become `If True And True Then`, because `2 And 1` is a perfectly valid, evaluatable expression. The conversion to `Boolean` does occur, but *after* the bitwise operation is resolved. `If 2 And 1 Then` resolves to `If 0 Then` which becomes `If False Then`.

Comment: @dwirony if Instr returned `TRUE` this would not be a problem, but it returns a Long and that is why one should always one should be explicit.  If the function returns `TRUE`/`FALSE` like `IsError()` or `IsNumeric` the `=True` can be left off.

Comment: But if the `String2` was found say, 3 times in `String1` in both `InStr()` scenarios then this would return `TRUE`... this is the kind of issue I'd be banging my head on the walls for for months trying to debug!

Comment: I posted this question and thought "i wish I still had access to that chat channel to just ask [you]" and sure enough you had the answer.  Thanks, Mat's Mug!  I got too used to being lazily implicit...