# How to search a cell for a comma and perform one of two actions based on whether a comma was found or not?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel worksheet of about 7,000 rows, each of which has a column with names that can be in various forms ([firstname lastname], [lastname, firstname], etc). I need to take all of those names and separate them into two separate columns, a first name and a last name column.

So what I want to do is write some code that will …

1. search for a comma in the string
2. if there is a comma, take all of the characters leading up to the comma and put them in the last name column. Then take all the characters after the comma and put them in the first name column
3. if there is no comma, just put the first string (first name) in the first name column and the second string (the last name) in the last name column.

It's been a while since I have messed around with visual basic code but I am thinking I can use some sort of `find()` method for the first step but after that I am completely lost. Any help would be appreciated.

---

After many edits....
Here is where I am at so far.

```
Sub WhatsInAName()
Dim N As Long, i As Long, v As String, M As Long, X As Long
N = Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To N
    v = Cells(i, "G").Value
    M = InStr(1, v, ",")
    X = InStr(1, v, "@")
    If M > 0 Then
        Cells(i, "H").Value = LTrim(Mid(v, M + 1))
        Cells(i, "I").Value = Left(v, M - 1)
    ElseIf X > 0 Then
        Cells(i, "H").Value = "email"
    Else
        M = InStr(1, v, " ")
        Cells(i, "H").Value = Left(v, M - 1)
        Cells(i, "I").Value = Mid(v, M + 1)
    End If
Next i
```

### End Sub

Edit #?

Ok so this is what I've essentially ended with. After seeing the data parsed out, it turns out there were a bunch of rows with 3 names or extra jibberish next to their name. For those I will just have to use Text-To-Columns until I figure out how to make my code more advanced to handle those issue. Thanks guys! This was a fun learning experience

Comment: *what I want to do is write some code* Nice, where is your code? where are you stuck? what errors are you getting? have you tried normal excel formulas?

Comment: So what you have to do is 1. research about how to use `find()` • 2. read the Microsoft documentation about the find method • 3. try something on your own • 4. if you then get stuck or errors that you cannot fix yourself. [Edit] your question, add your code and ask a question to it ([ask]).

Comment: Adding to what Foxfire said, what if the name has 2 words? how would the macro handle that? What you are asking for is fairly easy if there is only one word for the name and the last name, not if otherwise.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ This is what I am working on now but I am having trouble figuring out how to research parts of this (I think I am just asking the question in google the wrong way) so I was hoping people would know the methods I am looking for

Comment: *if there is no comma, just put the first string (first name) in the first name column and the second string (the last name) in the last name column.* What about names with 3 or more strings? names like `Jean Claude Van Damme`,

Comment: If your names and last names are only 2 strings, put your data inside a 2D array(x, 2), loop through the array. If the string has a comma split with the `Split()` function, give the arr(x, 1) the second item on the splitted string and arr(x, 2) the first item. If not just give the first word to the first column and the second word to the second. Paste back the array to the sheet.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns I added the code I have so far to the post. As far as I know there are no rows that have 3 names. If there are, I'd like to just toss those aside and manually go through them later. So with the code I just added, I am missing how to select values up to the comma or everything after the comma, as well as how to copy and paste

Comment: `InStr` doesn't return a `Boolean`, it returns a *position* - namely, the 1-based position of the comma inside the provided string. Don't treat it as a `Boolean` - [or you'll soon run into problems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57515088/1188513)

Comment: @MathieuGuindon thanks for pointing that out. I think I fixed it?

Comment: I think you want to capture the returned index into a local variable - if there's a comma, your logic will want to know where it's at. Also... with `= 0` you actually reversed the condition. Also, [`Left`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/left-function) and [`Right`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/right-function) aren't going to work like that.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon That's a good point, thanks. I have never written anything in Visual Basic before (I am a beginner in C# and Python) so this is going to be a reoccurring issue

Answer (score 1):

Well, not the best solution, but you can do this with normal formulas and then later on paste values.

You posted you have a column with names and you want to separate into 2 columns. I made something like this:

[image]

In cell `B2` my formula is:

```
=IF(LEN(A2)-1=LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2;" ";""));IF(IFERROR(SEARCH(",";A2);0)=0;TRIM(MID(A2;1;SEARCH(" ";A2)-1));TRIM(MID(A2;SEARCH(",";A2)+1;99)));"Manual fix")
```

In cell `C2` my formula is:

```
=IF(LEN(A2)-1=LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2;" ";""));IF(IFERROR (SEARCH(",";A2);0)=0;TRIM(MID(A2;SEARCH(" ";A2)+1;99));TRIM(MID(A2;1;SEARCH(",";A2)-1)));"Manual fix")
```

Some observations:

1. The formula will return `Manual Fix` if there are 2 or more spaces in the name (composed names)
2. The formula only works with 2 cases: case `lastname, firstname` and `firstname lastname`. Any other case will cause an error/unexpected result
3. If there are extra spaces at end or start of names, it will be counted as 2 or more spaces, so the formula will return `Manual Fix`

As you can see in the image, `Michael Jackson` and `Jackson, Michael` is splitted correctly. `Jean Claude Van Dame` returns `Manual Fix` due to being a composed name.

Try to adapt this to your needs.

**UPDATE:** Uploaded a file sample to GDrive in case you want to check the formulas on live. https://drive.google.com/file/d/17Agd57sclLlNuUbhdyaHmQgKUHcRd7hO/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
Sub WhatsInAName()
    Dim N As Long, i As Long, v As String, M As Long
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To N
        v = Cells(i, "A").Value
        M = InStr(1, v, ",")
        If M > 0 Then
            Cells(i, "B").Value = LTrim(Mid(v, M + 1))
            Cells(i, "C").Value = Left(v, M - 1)
        Else
            M = InStr(1, v, " ")
            Cells(i, "B").Value = Left(v, M - 1)
            Cells(i, "C").Value = Mid(v, M + 1)
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

For example:

[image]

This assumes that each cell contains either a **comma** or a **space** and the parsing is based on the first occurrence of the separator.  Also assumes:

1. input data in column **A**
2. no header row *(data starts in row #1)*

Comment: This looks like exactly what I was trying to do!!! Let me try it out really quickly and get back to you

Comment: This works! All I have to do now (I didn't forsee this problem) is make it skip anything that is an email and not a name. Thank you so much for your help, this is huge!

Comment: @Patrick  If you need more help, just add another Comment to this answer.

Comment: Awesome thanks! So I updated my code on the post. I basically took your code and tried to expand on the if-else statements to account for the presence of an @ symbol. However, now I am getting an error in on this line "Cells(i, "H").Value = Left(v, M - 1)" that says Run-time error '5':

Comment: @Patrick  You may have a **bad record**.  That is a record in which there is no **comma**, no **@**, and no **space**.