# How to iterate through some shapes in visio?

Tags: vba, visio

I'd like to iterate through some shapes in Visio, I have a solution that works but which is a bit low because there are a lot of shapes (a thousand maybe and I'm only interested to iterate on twenty or thirty of them) :

```
Dim shp As Visio.Shape
Dim pagShape As Visio.Shape
Set pagShape = Visio.ActivePage.PageSheet
For Each shp In Visio.ActivePage.Shapes

If InStr(shp.Data3, "_tag") Then
If StrComp(Replace(shp.Data3, "_tag", ""), name) = 0 Then
    shp.text = name
Else:
    shp.text = ""
End If
End If
Next shp
```

Is it possible to add some shapes in a kind of list instead of selecting all existing shapes ?
something like that :

```
For Each shp In List
```

thank you very much in advance :)

edit : I have done it that way :

the declaration and set part :

```
Public Collection_shp As Collection
Set Collection_shp = New Collection
```

When I create a label shape I add it to the collection :

```
Collection_shp.Add Item:=vso_sg
```

And the part with the loop :

```
Dim shp As Visio.Shape
For Each shp In Collection_shp 

If InStr(shp.Data3, "_tag") > 0 Then
If StrComp(Replace(shp.Data3, "_tag", ""), name) = 0 Then
    shp.text = name
    Else
    shp.text = ""
    End If
    End If
    Next shp
```

Comment: That said, wouldn't you need to iterate all shapes anyway in order to determine what shapes you're interested in? Or, you could hard-code them in an `Array`, but 20-30 items seems quite a lot of data to hard-code.

Comment: `If InStr(shp.Data3, "_tag") Then` is also a problem - `InStr` returns an index, not a Boolean. This [has caused problems before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57515088/1188513), don't let it bite you!

Comment: Will be faster if you `Exit For` after getting a hit (or are you expecting multiple matches?)  How many times do you need to run this loop ?  If you need multiple runs, you could load a Collection with all of the shapes with `shp.Data3 Like "*_tag"` and then instead iterate over that.

Comment: sorry I just saw your answers (left the office then I slept), I'll try them and I tell you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done it that way :

the declaration and set part :

```
Public Collection_shp As Collection
Set Collection_shp = New Collection
```

When I create a label shape I add it to the collection :

```
Collection_shp.Add Item:=vso_sg
```

And the part with the loop :

```
Dim shp As Visio.Shape
For Each shp In Collection_shp 

If InStr(shp.Data3, "_tag") > 0 Then
If StrComp(Replace(shp.Data3, "_tag", ""), name) = 0 Then
    shp.text = name
    Else
    shp.text = ""
    End If
    End If
    Next shp
```