# Is there a way to do Conditional Formatting for "Everything other than" in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I'm having trouble formatting an entire column based on what Political Affiliation a certain politician has. The more popular parties have already been formatted with the "Cell contains" formatting option, but I am trying to format everything else in the specific column that hasn't been picked up by the certain rules. These are other parties that are not popular, such as "Independent", "Rhinoceros Party", and other none popular parties. I've tried using the "Use Formula" rule to format it but have no luck in doing so. My idea is to format everything that is not the following.

- Political Affiliation, Liberal, Conservative, Green Party, NDP, Bloc Quebecois, People's Party, and " " (For empty cells)

`=NOT(OR("Political Affiliation", "Liberal", "Conservative", "Green Party", "NDP", "Bloc Québécois", "People's Party", " "))`

The column in F:F if that information is required as well. If this needs to be done in VBA and it's the only way, I don't mind. Thank you

Comment: Side note, "People's Party" has 0 elected officials. Might want to reconsider what "popular" stands for ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Put the "popular" parties somewhere in your worksheet/workbook.  Then, highlight them and create a Named Range.

Then, you can use a formula to check if the cell is in that named range.

Create a Conditional Format, with the Formula:

```
=AND(F2<>"",COUNTIF(popular_parties,$F2)=0)
```

Applies To Range: `$F$2:$F$100` (adjust as needed).  Then format as you wish.

[image]

Also, to note, you can use this to more easily mark those Popular Ones.  The Conditional Format formula on that would be `=AND(F2<>"",COUNTIF(popular_parties,$F2)>0)`. (Assuming you don't want the formatting to apply to empty cells.)

Edit: As @T.M. points out, if you include an empty cell in your named range, you can just do `=AND(F2<>popular_parties)` to get the non-popular parties CF.

Comment: I don't like that a count is being used as a Boolean value (I'd much rather have an explicit `COUNTIF(...)=0` and then there's no need for a `NOT` and everything is as explicit a no-hack as it gets, but maybe that's just me)

Comment: @MathieuGuindon - I agree, and to be honest, I only recently realized `COUNTIF()` can be used as Boolean, so perhaps am a little overzealous in using it :P  ...I agree with you and will update.

Comment: It's essentially the same hack that makes `InStr(...)` usable in an `If` statement, and [it will eventually bite you in the rear end](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57515088/1188513) if you keep abusing it =) (that said I don't think Excel's `AND` function uses bitwise logic, so there's that)

Comment: @MathieuGuindon - Thanks for that! I had been wondering if it was a good/bad/ugly practice, and that clarifies it a lot for me.  Cheers :D

Comment: You could include an empty cell to your named range `popular_parties` thus simplifying the condition to `=AND(F2<>popular_parties)` :-)

Comment: BTW note that conditional formatting is using local language (formulae) settings :-)

Comment: @T.M. - Oh good point!  In that example (`=AND(F2<>popular_parties)`), is the `AND()` necessary?

Comment: @BruceWayne, I fear it is, possibly because of array like evaluation - feel free to edit this as further possibility :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to hard-code these parties in your conditional formula, you could do something like:

```
=AND($F1<>"Political Affiliation", $F1<>"Liberal", $F1<>"Conservative", $F1<>"Green Party", $F1<>"NDP", $F1<>"Bloc Québécois", $F1<>"People's Party")
```

1. Select the entire F Column
2. Create a new conditional Formatting rule
3. Select **Use a formula to determine which cells to format**
4. Paste the above formula in the box